# Why random forests or decision trees can't give 100% precision? And How to handle huge noise in the middle?

Tags: machine-learning

If decision tree tries to determine splits based on highest amount of data belonging to similar class, why can't it split this particular data until each split has only 1 element in it,
which would lead to a 100% precision?

[image]

Comment: It would have a 100% precision on a training dataset, which would be a perfect example of overfitting

Comment: How would you handle the noise in the middle

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question: what exactly do you mean by split and why would you want only 1 element in each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having only 1 data point / case in every terminal node can cause over-fitting on the training dataset. To avoid this, test the constructed model using a particular summary statistic (eg. RMSE) against both the training and validation datasets. In Random Forest, the 'Out of Bag' sample can be used as a validation set. This is the proportion of data (roughly 37%) that is not used in the construction of every tree. The RMSE should be relatively similar between both the training and validation sets.